# Do the supremum and an increasing function commute?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f$ be a numerical function and $\phi$ a strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that
$$\sup_{x}\phi(f(x))=\phi(\sup_{x}f(x))?$$

Comment: What if $f$ is unbounded above?

Comment: @quasi Then the supremum doesn't exist on both sides... consider that excluded?

Comment: If $\phi$ continuous?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : don’t think what you say is correct. Take for example $\phi$ to be the $\arctan$ function, and $f(x)$ to be the identity function. Then $f(x)$ is unbounded, but the supremum on the left hand side certainly exists.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was just making a hunch.

Answer (score 3):

For a counterexample, let

$\;\;\;f(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$

$\;\;\;\phi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x/2 &\text{if}\;x < 1\\
x &\text{if}\;x \ge 1\\
\end{cases}
$

Comment: How did you come up with this counter-example?

Comment: @IshanDeo.  Math is an art, a logical art.